# В каких случаях может перезаписываться maildirsize?

Tags: exim

При настройке exim есть возможность настроить квоту пользователя с помощью файла maildirsize (что, по сути, является кэшем для других приложений, которым интересна квота пользователя).

Имеем следующие предпосылки:

1. как следует из документации, по умолчанию квота обрабатывает не все,
   что есть в Maildir, а только каталоги типа new и cur;
2. в файл maildirsize записываются все действия, связанные с получением и удалением писем (размер писем, на основании которого высчитывается оставшееся место);
3. Пользовательская квота хранится в БД, откуда выдирается exim'ом для проверки.

Исходя из предпосылок, следует, что если пользователь удалил письма из папки cur (читай - входящие) в корзину, в maildirsize добавится информация о размере удаленного письма, и квота пересчитается. НО - согласно предпосылке №1 папка корзины не учитывается при перерасчете квоты, а, следовательно, если файл maildirsize куда-либо денется - exim при получении нового письма пересчитает квоту согласно записи в БД и фактически занятому месту на диске.

В результате мы получаем ситуацию, что в maildirsize содержится информация о фактически занятом месте, но при этом, удаление файлов из корзины никак не влияет на пересчет квоты. И мы получаем значение квоты в X% (занятого места) даже при пустом ящике (X = % от размера файлов в каталогах, которые не учитываются при расчете квоты).

Понятно, что если добавить в расчет все каталоги в Maildir, проблема, скорее всего, исчезнет.

Текущий вопрос - в каких случаях exim может перезаписать имеющийся maildirsize и пересчитать квоту на основании фактически занятого места? Может, есть какой-то таймайут, или еще что-то подобное?

Перезаписать - имеется ввиду до того состояния, когда в файле остается только информация о квоте и количестве писем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, сам и отвечу.

Полный перерасчет maildirsize (а, соответственно, и его перезапись) происходит при получении письма, размер которого превышает оставшееся свободное место.

Соответственно, в новом расчете участвуют все каталоги из Maildir, и если после этого удалить все имеющиеся файлы, в т.ч. и из корзины (а мы помним из предпосылок, что удаление файлов из корзины не влияет на расчет квоты), по факту получим, что текущее значение занятого места согласно maildirsize не совпадает с фактически занятым местом на диске в Maildir (как раз та ситуация, что описана в вопросе).